# How to use JSX / React component with Nodemailer template?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, jsx, nodemailer

I have Next.js with Nodemailer and i want to use React / JSX components as templates in Nodemailer.

Currently in Nodemailer i have to write

```js
      html: `
        <div style="height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
          <div style="color: white;">${req.body.textarea}</div>
          <div style="height: 20px; background-color: red;">${req.body.textarea}</div>
        </div>
      `,
```

But is there a way to write React / JSX component and pass it to Nodemailer?

Googling i found `grandjs` but i think this might be to much for what i need so looking for something simpler.

I guess the idea should be to convert React JSX to plain HTML so i found `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` but i can't user that on Server Side

Comment: Why can't you use ReactDOMServer on server side?

Comment: I'm just being dump i have it working now, don't know at first i think i was getting errors but did not realised that i was first importing from wrong place, yeah i have this working now thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys me being dumb, i have this working now with `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`